# show scratch-card effect with the help of using scratch and win example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new in ios developement.i need to show scratch-card effect for an iPhone app after scratches if coupon  number is visible i need to show alert message How can i do this?.i have download sample code from  [iPhone - Scratch and Win Example](https://github.com/derekneely/Code-Repo/tree/master/iPhone%20-%20Scratch%20and%20Win%20Example) and also i have done showing below screen and scratches also works fine

if UILabel text is visible i want to show alert message How can i do this?

i have attached screen shot for your refference
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution ?

Comment: Hello @Ravindhiran have you Find Answer of this problem?  if you found please help me i have same issue like yours. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

i Found very nice Github example please take a look this and impliment as par you need hope this helps to you my Frnd.

[CGScratch](https://github.com/oyiptong/CGScratch) This is same thing that you want to apply.

[image]

review the code and check the visible area of Number else check che scration overImage is tatally removed of not if remove then show Alert.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `UIImageView` subclass that allows your `UIImageView` become a scratch card.

In your `storyboard` or `xib` set custom class of your `UIImageView` that represents your scratch image to `ScratchCardImageView`. Change `lineType` or `lineWidth` to change the appearance of the scratch lines.

Download [example](https://github.com/paleksandrs/ScratchCardImageView)

[image]

**Swift 3:**

```
import UIKit


class ScratchCardImageView: UIImageView {

    private var lastPoint: CGPoint?

    var lineType: CGLineCap = .square
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 20.0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard  let touch = touches.first else {

            return
        }

        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard  let touch = touches.first, let point = lastPoint else {

            return
        }

        let currentLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        eraseBetween(fromPoint: point, currentPoint: currentLocation)

        lastPoint = currentLocation
    }

    func eraseBetween(fromPoint: CGPoint, currentPoint: CGPoint) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

        image?.draw(in: self.bounds)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.addLine(to: currentPoint)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setShouldAntialias(true)
        context.setLineCap(lineType)
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        context.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context.addPath(path)
        context.strokePath()

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

**Updated**

With this solution touch events will be tracked only inside the `UIImageView` bounds. If you need touch events to start already outside your scratchcard, see [ScratchCardTouchContainer](https://github.com/paleksandrs/ScratchCardImageView) example

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this github tutorial for scratch:

1. https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STScratchView
2. https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See

Comment: how to get scratched area and scratchable area?