# Scratch Card effect in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-graphics

I am trying to implement a Scratch Card effect in Swift 3 for my app, I found some examples but they're on Objective C ([show scratch-card effect with the help of using scratch and win example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323589/show-scratch-card-effect-with-the-help-of-using-scratch-and-win-example))

In essence user swipes with finger on an image and reveals another image below their finger as they swipe.

Any one knows how to do this in Swift 3? Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScratchCard](https://github.com/joehour/ScratchCard) library. It has simple API, but I don't know is it Swift 3 compatible. Anyway, you can rewrite it or check its implementation.

Comment: Thank you sir! I am trying it out now

Comment: So i ran it, XCODE translates it to Swift 3, but then it will not run when i press the "play" button(it says "build succeeded with no errors but nothing happens/no simulator opens), it is also missing assets (image before/after) and has no storyboard file. I am a newbie to programming, any hints on the basic steps i need to take to rewrite it from scratch, which storyboard instruments to use and which classes/functions? Thanks again

Comment: Actually, this library doesn't have example project. You can create new project with Single View Application template, and manually add `ScratchUIView.swift` and `ScratchView.swift` into your project. Then you can add scratch view like that:

Comment: let scratchCardView  = ScratchUIView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 80, 320, 480),Coupon: "coupon image", MaskImage: "mask image", ScratchWidth: CGFloat(40))
    self.view.addSubview(ScratchCardView)

Comment: Much appreciated - I will try this

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch @Artem Novichkov

Comment: quick question - how can i extract the % of the image that has been scratched so far- say to display it on a label in the same view? I tried calling scratchCardView.getScratchPercent() on the label at TouchesBegan but it does nothing. Sorry if it's a noob question!

Comment: One question - do you want to show scratch percent in real time?

Comment: Yep preferably I would!

Comment: This scratch view have only `getAlphaPixelPercent()` function. You can add delegate or block to catch percent changing.

Answer (score 2):

Check this **Swift 3** example of [ScratchCardImageView](https://github.com/paleksandrs/ScratchCardImageView)

A simple `UIImageView` subclass that allows your `UIImageView` become a scratch card.

[image]

Comment: Thanks v much - I will check it out

Answer (score -1):

I found a library that suits your requirement. It is  Swift 3 compatible. 
Try this [SRScratchView](https://github.com/shamshiranees/SRScratchView)

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aw20.gif)

```
 var lineType: CGLineCap = .round
 var lineWidth: CGFloat = 30.0

 func scrachBetween(fromPoint: CGPoint, currentPoint: CGPoint) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

        image?.draw(in: self.bounds)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.addLine(to: currentPoint)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setShouldAntialias(true)
        context.setLineCap(lineType)
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        context.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context.addPath(path)

        context.strokePath()

        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()


        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
```